# How to respond to view after submitting the view in slack with bolt js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, slack, slack-api

Hi I've implemented one simple shortcut to get data from input but after submitting the view I couldn't get the response payload or it cannot update the view to acknowledge user. following is my simple code.

```
const { App } = require("@slack/bolt");
const app = new App({
  token: process.env.BOT_TOKEN,
  socketMode: true,
  signingSecret: process.env.SIGNIGN_SECRET,
  appToken: process.env.APP_TOKEN,
}); 
app.shortcut({ callback_id: 'open_modal', type: 'message_action' }, async ({ shortcut, ack, client }) => {
  try {
    await ack();
console.log("Ack:")
    
    const result = await client.views.open({
      trigger_id: shortcut.trigger_id,
      callback_id: "new-task-modal",
      view: {
        type: "modal",
        title: {
          type: "plain_text",
          text: "My App",
        },
        submit: {
          type: "plain_text",
          text: "Submit",
          emoji: true,
        },
        close: {
          type: "plain_text",
          text: "Cancel",
        },
        blocks: [
          {
            "type": "input",
            "element": {
                "type": "plain_text_input",
                "action_id": "plain_text_input-action"
            },
            "label": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Label",
                "emoji": true
            }
        }
        ],
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
app.view({ callback_id: 'new-task-modal', type: 'message_action' }, async({ shortcut, ack, view, body }) => {
  try {
    console.log("New task modal",view.state.values );
    await ack();
    
        let result = await client.views.update({
          view_id: body.view.id,
          view: {
            type: "modal",
            title: {
              type: "plain_text",
              text: "My App",
              emoji: true,
            },
            close: {
                type: "plain_text",
                text: "Cancel",
              },
            blocks: [
              {
                type: "section",
                text: {
                  type: "plain_text",
                  text: "This is a plain text section block.",
                  emoji: true,
                },
              },
            ],
          }
        });
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})
```

`app.shortcut()` function works fine and create one view but after submitting that view it couldn't hit to `app.view()` function to update the view so is there any way to update the current view.

Answer (score 0):

The `callback_id` in the `client.views.open` call should be under the `view` field, not on the root level.

```
const result = await client.views.open({
  trigger_id: shortcut.trigger_id,
- callback_id: "new-task-modal",
  view: {
+   callback_id: "new-task-modal",
    type: "modal",
    title: {
      type: "plain_text",
      text: "My App",
    },
...
```